# Add data to new line if file already contains data - Java

Tags: java, file, csv

Trying to output data to a CSV file. I'd like to output the CSV headings corresponding to the data only if the file is empty. Else, I'd like to add the data to a new line in the file.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the file is empty by checking the length of the file.  This will basically tell you if the file is empty.

```
File file = new File(path);

if(file.length() == 0){
    // Write Header.
}
```

And if the file has data, open the writer in append mode.  This can  be done using the second parameter to the FileWriter constructor.  Pass true to open the file in append mode.

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
```